# PHP convert time to date

Tags: php, date, time

I have date value like so `1369195200000` and I tried to convert it to date like so

```
$date = 1369195200000;
$result = date("Y-m-d", $date);
```

but it returns like so `45358-01-25` obviously the year is wrong....is there away to get the correct year? The `$date` is coming from a database.

Comment: I expect that it includes miliseconds. Divide it by 1000, and you get a much more plausible result.

Comment: that date is correct, given your input.

Comment: What format is that time in? its not unix timestamp, it doesnt appear to be a datetime either, how is that number created? Edit: andrewsi intuition seems to be correct, divided by 1000 it becomes a likely unix timestamp

Answer (score 5):

The time is in milliseconds, it needs to be divided by 1000.

```
$date = 1369195200000;
$result = date("Y-m-d", $date / 1000);
```

Comment: Beware that this may not always work as you expect on 32-bit servers.
In this case, it could be better to treat the number as a string and strip the last 3 characters.