# Generate multiple CSV files - mysql PHP

Tags: php, csv, foreach, while-loop

I have made this PHP script that should take an array and for each element in the array - generate a csv file. Unfortunately something is wrong. It doesn't store any of the files in the directory specified. But it doesn't return any errors neither. Maybe someone can see the problem?

```
$ids = json_decode($_POST['jsonarray']); // array sent with ajax
$start = $_POST['start']; // date sent with ajax
$end = $_POST['end']; // date sent with ajax

$start_date = date('yyyy-mm-dd', strtotime($start)); // format dates to sql firendly
$end_date = date('yyyy-mm-dd', strtotime($end));

$toZip = array(); // Prepare array to files for zip

if(is_array($ids)) {
    foreach ($ids as $key => $qr)
    {
        // Get labels first
        // Here we prepare the first line in the .CSV file
        $tb = $qr . '_labels';
        $sql = $user_pdo->query("SELECT * FROM $tb");
        $head_array = array('Log ID', 'Timestamp');
        while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
        // This array is the first line in the .CSV file
            $head_array[] = $row['label'];
        }

        // Get ready for looping through the database
        $table = $qr . '_data';
        $results = $user_pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE timestamp BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date;");
        $results->bindParam(':start_date', $start_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $results->bindParam(':end_date', $$end_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $results->execute();

        // Pick a filename and destination directory for the file
        $filename = "temp/db_user_export_".time().".csv";

        // Actually create the file
        // The w+ parameter will wipe out and overwrite any existing file with the same name
        $handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');

        // Write the spreadsheet column titles / labels
        fputcsv($handle, $head_array);


        // Write all the user records to the spreadsheet
        foreach($results as $row)
        {
                // amount of rows is unknown
            $rows = $row->rowCount();
            $insert_array = array();
            for ($i=0; $i<=$rows; $i++)
            {
                // function goes here
                $insert_array[] = $row[$i];
            }

            fputcsv($handle, $insert_array);
        }

        // Finish writing the file
        fclose($handle);

        $toZip[] = $filename;
    }
}
```

Example on `var_dump($ids);`

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "t23ry"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "6us32"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "se43z"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "o00gq"
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `$ids`? `var_dump($ids);`

Comment: The return value for json_decode is, according to PHP.net's docs, "mixed". At times json_decode will return an object.

Comment: What may be the problem that your files are not getting written is the `temp/` folder declaration in `$filename = "temp/db_user_export_".time().".csv";` - Try setting it to `$filename = "db_user_export_".time().".csv";` for testing purposes.

Comment: I have tested some more.. I can create the csv files now, but only the first row is written. no additional content is made. (the problem was that all the .csv files had the same name `$filename = "temp/db_user_export_".time().".csv";` but by adding the unique `$qr`-variable that solved that issue.)

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted Great, glad to know it was solved.

Comment: Not completely though :) still no content from the database even though I know there should be something.. But I have fount an issue. When I am converting the date I paste in a value of e.g. `10/01/2013` but it converts it to `"string(18) "13131313-1010-0101"`

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted That's because `time()` uses the UNIX timestamp format. You need to convert it. Have a look at the manual on that function http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Comment: Silly question: but how do I do that? - I was guided to this method.

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted See this Q/A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943683/php-convert-time-to-date then just use that variable (`$result`) in your query.

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted Why not just use the built-in datetime function in MySQL? That way you won't have to convert anything.

Comment: but it is a posted ajax variable. Not an SQL variable.

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted Ah ok. So, how are you making out with the link I gave you?

Comment: Try this `$date = 1369195200000; $result = date("Y-m-d", $date / 1000); $filename = "temp/db_user_export_".$result.".csv"; echo $filename;` this outputted **temp/db_user_export_2013-05-22.csv** for me. However I suggest you add another variable to that, to generate a unique number.

Comment: Ahh.. you misunderstood. It is not the filename time. it is the dates: `$start_date = date('yyyy-mm-dd', strtotime($start)); // format dates to sql firendly
$end_date = date('yyyy-mm-dd', strtotime($end));`

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted Yes, see my comment just above. It outputted as a "date". That is what you want, right?

Comment: I actually don't know. I wish to use the dates in my sql query. But I don't know how I should implement them. I found this site http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/between.php that says it should be used as a date, but the "to_date" function doesn't work, so I really don't know how I should use it

Comment: Well it depends on how your variables have been stored in your DB. That's why it's important to use the proper method right away, then having to deal with it later. What is the field type set to for `start_date` and `end_date`?

Comment: the sql table is a `TIMESTAMP` and the start-date and end_date is defined to make the "between" statement in sql. This way I should be able to output where timestamp is between 01/10/2013 and 15/10/2013 for example

Comment: You need to change `to_date` to your field name that's in your DB. Don't use that code from the link you gave me as an "out of the box" method.

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted By the way, I noticed you have 2x `$` in `$$end_date` but not your `$start_date` -  I don't know if this is intentional or relevant.

Comment: thanks.. didn't solve anything, but definitely was a typo.

Comment: it seems to, that my biggest problem is the second SQL query. it is definitely the dates in the sql query that make troubles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. After a long time searching and playing around, I saw that this function

```
    foreach($results as $row)
    {
            // amount of rows is unknown
        $rows = $row->rowCount();
        $insert_array = array();
        for ($i=0; $i<=$rows; $i++)
        {
            // function goes here
            $insert_array[] = $row[$i];
        }

        fputcsv($handle, $insert_array);
    }
```

didn't work because of following:

1. `$rows = $row->rowCount();` has to be `$rows = count($row);`
2. The number of string in the returned `$row` array was higher than expected so I needed to change my select statement to `$results = $user_pdo->query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE timestamp >= '$start' AND timestamp <= '$end'";, PDO::FETCH_NUM);`. This will only give me the rows in numeric order, which will make the `$row[$i] -> array` work.
3. Also as you can see, I changed the prepared statement to a query instead, and also changes the start date and end date variables to be unformatted.

This really took some time, but it is finally working. Thanks a lot for all the support guys.

Comment: Ah yes, very good. I'm glad it finally worked out. I didn't know what else to tell you earlier. Problem solved :) cheers (`+1`)

Answer (score 0):

*fputcsv* only outputs a line at a time. Change this:

```
        for ($i=0; $i<=$rows; $i++)
        {
            // function goes here
            $insert_array[] = $row[$i];
        }

        fputcsv($handle, $insert_array);
```

To this:

```
        for ($i=0; $i<=$rows; $i++)
        {
            // function goes here
            fputcsv($handle, $row[$i]);
        }
```

Comment: I know :) Thats why I make an array of all the `$row['column']` before I write the line.

Comment: Giving fputscsv an array of arrays will not result in all of the content being written based on what I am seeing in the PHP.net docs.